# Extracting multiple email address from excel cell /excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, unix, vba, extract, google-spreadsheets

Is there a way to extract multiple email address from excel cell /excel file

```
    |   A   |   B                                                                  
----|-------------
1   |HTML   |
    |Content|
    |   1   |
----|-------|-----
2   |HTML   |
    |Content|
    |   2   |
----|-------|-----
N Rows|     |
```

More or less the content is the same in columns

HTML Content in column one row one

---

```
cid=9498&peid= **xyz9000@gmail.com** &mbrid=cf7cc75d395cbf901f73967b1267db42 style="text-decoration: none;  color: blue;">Update</a> contact/membership info.<font style="font-size:14px" face="Verdana" color="#000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="font-size:12px" face="Verdana" color="#3c3c3c"><a href=https:///fe_web_member_subscription_verify.php?oeid= 
**navee@centra.com**&cid=9498 style="text-decoration: none;  color: blue;">Subscribe</a> to receive requirements & resumes
                                                                    </font>        
                                                            </p>
                                                       </td>
                                            </tr>

                              <tr>
                                                   <td colspan="2"  valign="middle">
                                                            <p style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"> 
                                                                    <font style="font-size:15px" color="#3C3C3C" face="Verdana" >
                                        <br><u>From</u>:<br>
                                               Navee ,<br>
                                               Centra<br>                                            
                                                                           qwerty@centra.com<br>
                                                                           <span style="background-color: #FFFF00"><b>Reply to:</b></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;navee@centra.com<br><br>

                                                                    </font>        
                                                            </p>
                                                  </td>
                                            </tr>  

                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td  colspan="2" valign="middle">
                                                            <br><p><strong>Big
```

HTML Content in column one row two

---

```
cid=9498&peid= **xyz9000@gmail.com** &mbrid=cf7cc75d395cbf901f73967b1267db42 style="text-decoration: none;  color: blue;">Update</a> contact/membership info.<font style="font-size:14px" face="Verdana" color="#000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="font-size:12px" face="Verdana" color="#3c3c3c"><a href=https:///fe_web_member_subscription_verify.php?oeid= 
**navee@centra.com**&cid=9498
```

I tried to use online tools available on the internet but they are of no use / they extract only the first available email address in the excel field.

https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel/excel-extract-email-address-from-string.html

There are n number of rows.

Is there a way to extract multiple email address from excel cell

Required output -
extract emails and save them in a separate spread sheet or in the adjacent column

=========================

---

Input Format 3

#

For the following HTML code present in the excel cell I'm able to extract only the first occurence of the email that I get but not all the multiple email address mentioned.

```
            <p align="center"  style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:30px; margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:25px;">
                <table width="1024" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  border="0" >
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"  style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ff7373; " valign="bottom">
                            <p style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"> 
                                <font style="font-size:12px" color="#3C3C3C" face="Verdana" >
                                    <a href=https://house.com/powerhouse/fe_web_member_unsubscription.php?cid=4870&teid=volcan9@gmail.com&mbrid=cf7cc75d395cbf901f73967b1267db42 style="text-decoration: none; color: red;">Remove/unsubscribe</a><font style="font-size:14px" face="Verdana" color="#000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="font-size:12px" face="Verdana" color="#3c3c3c"><a href=https://house.com/powerhouse/fe_web_member_update.php?cid=4870&peid=volcan9@gmail.com&mbrid=cf7cc75d395cbf901f73967b1267db42 style="text-decoration: none;  color: blue;">Update</a> contact/membership info.<font style="font-size:14px" face="Verdana" color="#000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="font-size:12px" face="Verdana" color="#3c3c3c"><a href=https://house.com/powerhouse/fe_web_member_subscription_verify.php?oeid=mod.s@solutionsinc.com&cid=4870 style="text-decoration: none;  color: blue;">Subscribe</a> to receive requirements
                                </font> 
                            </p>
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"  valign="middle">
                            <p style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"> 
                                <font style="font-size:15px" color="#3C3C3C" face="Verdana" >
                                        <br><u>From</u>:<br>
                                       mod,<br>
                                       Solution<br>                                            
                                       mod.s@solutionsinc.com<br>
                                       <span style="background-color: #FFFF00"><b>Reply to:</b></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;mod.s@solutionsinc.com<br><br>

                                </font> 
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  

                        <tr >
                            <td  width="800" valign="top"  style="border-top: solid 1px #333399; ">
                                <p align="justify" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"> 
                                <font style="font-size:12px" color="#666666" face="Verdana">
                                     <a href="http://www.res.com/#!products/c5n6" style="text-decoration: none; color: red" title="Click to view more details">.</a>
                                </font>
                            </p>
                            </td>

                                <td    valign="top" style="border-top: solid 1px #333399; ">
                                    <p  align="right" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">  
                                <font style="font-size:10px" color="#3C3C3C" face="Verdana">

                                </font>
                            </p>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                </table><br>
            </p>
```

Comment: Yes there are several ways of doing this. `kutools` is supposed to work for multiple email addresses.  What other options have you tried, and what is the issue.  Which of the various tags (`unix`, `vba`, `google-spreadsheets`, `excel`) do you want to use?  What kind of output do you want?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Required output -
extract emails and save them in a separate spread sheet or in the adjacent column. I would like to use the excel vba or which ever one is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This User Defined Function (UDF) will return an array of the existing email addresses in the referenced cell.

The individual addresses can then be retrieved in a variety of methods:

- Use the INDEX function
- Enter the function as an array across several cells
- Use it in a macro to perform specialized actions that you may require.

The character of an email address is determined by the regex pattern `sPat` and described in detail below.

You put the UDF into a regular module

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtrEmail(S As String) As String()
    Dim sTemp() As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b" 'Regex for emails
    Dim I As Long
    
'Initialize Regex engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ReDim sTemp(1 To MC.Count)
        I = 0
        For Each M In MC
            I = I + 1
            sTemp(I) = M
        Next M
    End If
End With
ExtrEmail = sTemp
End Function
```

One way of using it is shown in the screenshot below (using the INDEX function). The formula is entered in `B1` and filled to the right and down.  The `IFERROR` clause causes it to return a null string if there are fewer matches than cells filled.

**Edit:** *Picture changed to show all three examples*

[image]

## Regex Pattern Explanation

### Emailaddress

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AwD7.png) `\b`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z0-9._%+-]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
  - [A character in the range between “0” and “9”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `0-9`
  - [A single character from the list “._%+”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `._%+`
  - [The literal character “-”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match the character “@” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `@`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z0-9.-]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [A character in the range between “A” and “Z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `A-Z`
  - [A character in the range between “0” and “9”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `0-9`
  - [The literal character “.”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `.`
  - [The literal character “-”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
- [Match the character “.” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\.`
- [Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z]{2,}`

  - [Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,}`
- [Assert position at a word boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AwD7.png) `\b`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: @Matt If it is working for you, could you please mark my answer as accepted?  Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have tried your solution for the Input format 3. Unfortunately your solution is not working. It is extracting only the first occurence of the email. Not all the multiple emails present in the cell are being extracted. Not sure if the issue is because of the input data or I'm executing it wrong - =IFERROR(INDEX(ExtrEmail($A1),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")

Comment: @Matt Seems to work OK here with your just added Input Format 3 data.  And your formula appears OK, assuming your data is A1.  I'll post a screenshot of my results with all your info